# Display another modal dialog box on top of other modal dialog boxes in Java

Tags: java, dialog

I have a rather strange question:
I have a Java application which uses "applications" (plugins) run in different threads.
Most of these plugins will be written by other people and I will have no control over the code. The application requires a permanent connection to the Internet as information is constantly transferred between the server and app. What I want to do is have a thread which runs in the backround checking to see if there is a Internet connection. If the connection drops I want the ENTIRE application (and all its threads) to pause, display a message and when reconnected resume. I want this dialog box to be displayed above all other dialog boxes (modal or not). I'm thinking of something like the Windows Vista User Account Control Alerts.

How can I do this?

Comment: By the way, if you do this, any plugin that displays a modal dialog will lock up the whole GUI of all applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this at all reasonably, you need to use Java 6, as previous versions simply don't give you the granularity of modality you need.

Here are the [modality options](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/Desktop/javase6/modality/).

For this to work effectively, you would have to have each plugin honor a contract to not use Toolkit modality (the default behavior is that a modal dialog box locks everything up, to keep backwards compatibility). Application modality would seem to be a great fit for you, but I don't see that you can implement this in Java. This seems to be up to the JVM vendor, as far as I could find.